# Hibernate or resume failed

Tags: arch-linux

ASUS K50AF, 2G RAM

I want hibernate and suspend my system with systemd( systemctl hibernate and  systemctl suspend).
Suspend looks like work correctly, but hibernate(maybe resume) isn't wokring: 
When I "hibernate" and power on again, system seemed be frozen at a black screen

#### mkinitcpio.conf

> > HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block resume filesystems usbinput fsck"

#### grub.cfg

> > linux    /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=06c94dc9-7166-43ec-947f-82d5c48be181 ro  quiet resume=UUID=dbaf6e98-b167-4db2-9090-a7f205e546ee

#### $ swapon -s

> > Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
> >
> > /dev/sda7                                  partition    2160704    0    -1

sda7's UUID=dbaf6e98-b167-4db2-9090-a7f205e546ee

```
# cat /var/log/kernel.log|grep PM:
Dec 16 10:11:50 bearhouse kernel: [ 2447.862363] PM: Hibernation mode set to 'platform'
Dec 16 10:11:50 bearhouse kernel: [ 2447.937849] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
Dec 16 10:11:50 bearhouse kernel: [ 2447.937852] PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000e4000
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e4000 - 0000000000100000
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    0.210047] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7ff8e000-0x7ffcffff] (270336 bytes)
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    1.382465] PM: Checking hibernation image partition UUID=dbaf6e98-b167-4db2-9090-a7f205e546ee
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    1.588375] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    3.373893] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    3.373898] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:7 present
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    3.373899] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    3.374147] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Dec 16 10:13:28 bearhouse kernel: [    3.374151] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Dec 16 10:14:51 bearhouse kernel: [  100.626296] PM: Hibernation mode set to 'platform'
Dec 16 10:14:51 bearhouse kernel: [  100.659946] PM: Marking nosave pages: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
Dec 16 10:14:51 bearhouse kernel: [  100.659949] PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000e4000
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e4000 - 0000000000100000
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    0.210163] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7ff8e000-0x7ffcffff] (270336 bytes)
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    1.381585] PM: Checking hibernation image partition UUID=dbaf6e98-b167-4db2-9090-a7f205e546ee
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    1.587723] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    3.550784] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    3.550789] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:7 present
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    3.550790] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    3.559535] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Dec 16 14:41:22 bearhouse kernel: [    3.559539] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

Comment: I had asked the same question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/832498/pm-hibernation-image-not-present-or-could-not-be-loaded). Maybe it can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

After editing your mkinitcpio.conf file, did you rebuild the images by running "mkinitcpio -p 
linux"? (Change linux to the name of your kernel if you have a custom one. See the .preset files in /etc/mkinitcpio.d/ for a list of names).

(This should be a comment, but for I don't yet have permission to do that.)