# PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded

Tags: linux, hibernate, systemd

After hibernating with `systemctl hibernate`, the system boots normally as if it had been shutdown.
I have the resume parameter in the kernel line and the resume hook in mkinitcpio.conf

These are the relevant kernel messages:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i swap
[    0.000000] Command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda2 rw resume=/dev/sda4
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda2 rw resume=/dev/sda4
[    0.350295] PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/sda4
[    8.776686] Adding 8191996k swap on /dev/sda4.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8191996k FS
$ dmesg | grep -i hibern
[    0.350295] PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/sda4
[    0.350301] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

So the only remaining possibility is that `systemctl` **didn't write to disk**. In fact, when I run the command, the screen first goes blank for a couple of seconds, then I can see my terminal again, and finally it shutdowns itself.

I read that pm-utils do not work very well with systemd, so I wouldn't want to switch to those. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I fixed it by tweaking the `resume=`  kernel option.   Find out the UUID of your swap partition and then try to `resume=UUID=.......`

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: Thanks for the help! I'll try your solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you please share your solution here?

Comment: @abforce Following Adrian's solution worked for me. Replace normal paths with UUIDs in the kernel options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate @AdrianRatnapala's comment, you have to:

1. Find uuid of your swap partition. Suppose the partition is sdb3, then

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdb3
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 окт.   9 08:59 1dd7e123-1f82-45f0-a202-0ff3ea6f081a -> ../../sdb3
   ```
2. Open `/etc/default/grub`, and find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="`. Add there between the quotes `resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/your-swap-uuid`. As an example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/1dd7e123-1f82-45f0-a202-0ff3ea6f081a"
   ```
3. Run as a root `update-grub`
4. A reboot is needed to use the new kernel command-line.

Comment: I don't use Grub but the essence of the procedure is the same!

Comment: UUID of my swap changes every reboot so this doesn't work :(

Comment: @Petr this is weird… UUID should only change upon reformatting. I found [alike bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/105490) though, but this is dated by 2008 year. Okay, just for the safe case try `sudo mkswap </dev/partition-name>`, then check its UUID with `sudo blkid </dev/partition-name>`. If it still would change upon reboot, I'd suggest you to ask a question at unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Petr ah, another thing to try before asking — you could manually set UUID of swap with `sudo swaplabel -U <NEW-UUID> </dev/partition-name>`. You could generate new UUID with `uuidgen` utility.

Comment: I think it's easier and safer to get the UUID with `blkid`. `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` won't give you a useful output if you are using lvm.

Comment: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` in Arch Linux. :)

Comment: Did not work for me still getting `Jan  6 15:34:55 hostName kernel: [    2.111487] PM: Checking hibernation image partition 86cfa90d-b28e-4915-8856-47750aac8903
Jan  6 15:34:55 hostName kernel: [    2.165479] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my success here because it might help others with this issue. Bottom line, for those who want to skip the details: After changing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in the /etc/default/grub file and doing update-grub, do a complete Shut Down and Restart of the machine before trying out the hibernation.

The details: I have just successfully implemented hibernation on the Linux installation of my Lenovo ThinkPad T480 (dual boot Debian 9 and Windows) following the above advice to add a resume=UUID= parameter to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in /etc/default/grub. But it did not work the first time. I added the parameter, ran update-grub, and tried to hibernate (systemctl-hibernate). The system seemed to hibernate, but when powered back on the previous screen image would appear and remain for several seconds before the machine went into the login screen that usually presents on initial startup; all work present before hibernation was gone. I finally noticed (grep 'command line' syslog) that the changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line had NOT been passed to the kernel. After more effort, I found that a complete shutdown and restart WOULD result in the changed line being passed (grep 'command line' syslog again). After that, systemctl hibernate induced hibernation as before, but at power on the previous state of the machine was restored correctly.

Comment: This answer provides some additional useful information that could be appended to the accepted answer. In particular, the need to reboot in order to use the new kernel command-line is obvious to experienced Linux users, but might trip up new users.